# What kind of insect is this and what is it doing?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I live in Denmark and found these two insects on a tree. I'm interested in the big fly and have the following questions:

- What kind of fly is it?
- What is it doing with the little fly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is some what looking like a stonefly.. but if you want a clear identification of this insect you can visit this site.. http://www.insectidentification.org/

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a [Robber Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae). Those are predatory.

[image]

Comment: I'd make that __certainly__ a robber fly.